# Using QGIS C++ API to open .sfx

Tags: qgis, c++

Trying to load layers from .SXF:

```
 QgsProviderRegistry::instance(qgisPluginPath);

   pLayerFromProvider = new QgsVectorLayer(
               filePath.toUtf8(),
               SL_LayerList.at(index.row()).toUtf8() ,
               "ogr");

   pLayerRenderer = new QgsSingleSymbolRenderer(
                    QgsSymbol::defaultSymbol(pLayer->geometryType()));

   pLayer->setRenderer(pLayerRenderer);

   if (pLayer->isValid()) qDebug("Layer is valid"); 
   else                   qDebug("Layer is NOT valid");

   pLayerSet = new QList <QgsMapLayer*>;
   pLayerSet->append(pLayer);

   QgsProject::instance()->addMapLayers( *pLayerSet );

 //pMapCanvas was created
   pMapCanvas->setLayers(*pLayerSet);
   pMapCanvas->resize(500,500);

   pMapCanvas->refresh();
```

Rectangle appears on widget only.
What's wrong?

Comment: Can you confirm that QGIS loads this if you add it as a new vector layer using the main QGIS application and that you aren't getting that "Layer is NOT valid" debug message?